# Order by score total ASC

Tags: php

I could not get rid of a problem and want your help.

This is what I want to do briefly;

There are job postings in Table A, and these job posts have ratings in table B. When I list the job postings, I want to list the job postings by the highest percentage percentage.

```
$query = $db->query("SELECT job_listing.id,
        FROM job_listing
            LEFT JOIN job_order_ratings ON job_order_ratings.job_id = job_listing.id
        WHERE job_listing.job_status = 2 
        ORDER BY *** ASC")->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

[score table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1j1yk.png)

I normally calculate the score rating of a job this way. I want to list the points according to the total rate while listing

```
public function rateTotal($rate1, $rate2, $rate3, $count= '')
{
      $rate_total = $rate1 + $rate2 + $rate3;
      $total = $rate_total / $count;
      return number_format(round(($total / 3), 1), 1, '.', '');
}
```

Since there are three ratings, I divide it into the last three

When I list job postings in sql query, I want it to list by percentage. It has to calculate just like I did in the rateTotal function.

I'm sorry for my bad english

Comment: You can get the query to do all the work, if you tell us how the `score table` is linked to these other tables

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "SELECT
              job_listing.id,
              FORMAT((SUM(column1 + column2 + column3)/ COUNT(column)) / 3, 2) AS 'rating
        FROM job_listing
        LEFT JOIN job_order_ratings ON job_order_ratings.job_id = 
                 job_listing.id
    WHERE job_listing.job_status = 2 ORDER BY job_order_ratings.field DESC"
```

Did you try this way?
When u use ASC (ascending), you will order numbers from smaller to bigger, if you use DESC (descending) is from bigger to smaller number 10,9,8,7,6,5...

Comment: https://ibb.co/sbmbQ3R
https://ibb.co/S0Rzh9G

As in these images, I calculate the rates with the rateTotal function. I want it to calculate in sql like this and list by rate

Comment: FORMAT((SUM(`column1` + `column2` + `column3`)/ COUNT(`column`)) / 3, 2) AS 'rating' 
I edited my post, maybe will help you to calculate the ratings